# Docker isn't restarting

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/influxdata/sandbox/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). Just to give a bit background the git repo has a shell script named "sandbox" when i run "./sandbox up" it just does "docker-compose up -d --build" after setting some varables.

I just added

```
restart: always
```

to all the services in the existing .yml file and restarted all the containers. All the containers are up and running as expected. In order to check restart functionality, i just closed on the contained but it never automatically restated.

```
docker stop sandbox_chronograf_1_de92359427a0
```

The container exited with code 0 but this should not stop it from restarting because the restart is set to **always** but not on **on-failure**

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what state your container is, u can't start if it's in created state for eg, a restart is usually performed for a running container. So docker start.

Comment: How to find if docker is in created state ? The machine will be deployed at client location and I expect it to restart when ever it exits.

Comment: Try with docker rm -f <container_name> to shut down the container(which is not a graceful shutdown) instead of stop.